# clang-8 Is it possible to suppress note: expanded from macro

Tags: macros, clang, static-analysis

Is there any way to make clang-8 print warning without its further explanation if it is expanded from macro

```
note: expanded from macro
```

I would like to get only the warning without note: part

Is it possible?